# Questions on the law of total multivariate probability

Tags: probability

I am wondering whether these formulations are established:

$P(Y|X,A)=\int_z P(Y|z,A)P(z|X,A) dz$

$P(Y|X,A)=\int_z P(Y|Z)P(z|X,A) dz$

The $Y$, $A$ $X$ are the events and $z$ are the variable.

And if so, how to prove and comprehend them?

thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly is meant with the notations like $p(Y\mid X,A)$ and $P(Y\mid Z,A)$? Also: is there any difference between e.g. $p(Y\mid X,A)$ and $P(Y\mid X,A)$? In the integrals on RHS variable $Z$ seems to be overloaded with meanings.

Comment: The $p(Y|X,A)$ and $P(Y|X,A)$ are the same. I am sorry about making this typo.

Comment: BTW, could you explain the meaning of variable $Z$ overloaded?

Comment: I see $Z$ as part of integral sign ($\int_Z$, why?) and also as intergrating variable ($dZ$). Do the notations stand for conditional PDF'S maybe? Is $Z $ a random variable or a normal variable? Questions like this cross my mind.

Comment: How to integrate over events (I mean  $Z $)? For that it must be a variable.

Comment: I am sorry for making a mistake again. The $Y$, $A$, $Z$ are all random variables.

Comment: Okay, and what *exactly* is denoted $P(Y\mid X,A)$? Further if $Z$ is a random variable then you cannot write $\int\cdots dZ$.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor in probability. May I ask you why it can not be formed as $\int dZ$. Or can I write as $P(Y|X,A) = \sum_{Z_i} P(Y|Z_i,A)P(Z_i|X,A) $ ?  Thanks so much!

Comment: If $Z$ is a random variable having PDF $f_Z$ then you can write things like $\mathbb EZ=\int zf_Z(z)dz$ where the small $z$ is a variable, but certainly not a random variable like $Z$. This distinction must be made to keep things clear. Still you gave no answer on my question: what exactly is denoted by $P(Y\mid X,A)$? If $Y,X,A$ are events then that is clear (conditional distribution of event $Y$ if events $X,A$ occur) but you said that $Y,X,A$ are not events but random variables. So it is still unclear for me. What is the meaning of $Z_i$ in the RHS in the expression in your last comment?

Comment: Thanks so much for your kindly reply.  I finally get what you mean. The Y, X,A are the events while the $z_i$ is the variable $i$ of random variable $Z$. I hope the equation is correct now.